# get last record of a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that lets users create new records, 

In the field that is the id that auto-increments i want the user to see the record number that this record is by somehow showing latest value+1 in the fields value.

I was thinking of something like:

```
<input type="text"  value="<?php echo $myQuery['recordId'].length+1"/>
```

But that doesn't work.

Again, this is only to get the default value in the `<input>`

Instead of having to look up the last id, And this form is only used by one admin.

Comment: What if two users load the form at the same time? They would get the same id, but they can't both save to that id.

Comment: Good question, but this is for the admin.

Comment: You'd have the same problem if the admin opens two copies of the page in separate browser windows/tabs.

Comment: Or if the size of the project grows to include multiple admins. It is better to avoid race conditions at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the one plus the highest id by selecting it:

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table
```

But like David said, you're not guaranteed this will be the id that is used, because 2 people could load the page at about the same time.

Comment: This will fail if the record that previously held the highest value has been deleted.

Comment: Yeah, it'll also fail if 2 insert pages are loaded at the same time, then each is filled out.  One will have an id of (max id + 1), and the other will have an id of (max id + 2).

Answer (score 1):

To get the last id relevant to that connection, use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

In your case you'll have to insert an empty record in the db before you can guarantee that it will count. It will leave a lot of empty records if the users don't proceed, but you can do a cleanup every time the form is loaded by deleting records created more than one hour ago that don't have a title value or something like that.

Comment: This will only work if a record has actually been inserted, and will fail if other connections have inserted a record since.

Answer (score 1):

if you absolutely need it to be an integer, you can always create a special table with only one auto_increment column, insert to it, get the last_insert_id() and use that.  this is kind of mimicking the sequences in oracle.  the ids that dont get used will go waste, but the other problems associated with multiuser scenarios will not occur.  The following code copied from mysql documentation on [information functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).  Go there to read on the promises of this code.

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Now back to my own words. If it does not have to be an integer you can use [guid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier).  There is a [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function in php, and there is a [uuid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function in mysql. the theory says even if everyone keeps generating guids independently all the time, every guid will be unique.

So this is one way of doing it:

```
<?php
    $query = "select uuid()";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $uuid = $row[0];
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $uuid; ?>"/>
```